# Why is that when I changed file extension to .php, it doesn't reflect on the server?

Tags: php, xampp

When I pasted my Portfolio folder on htdocs there's a file inside named 'contact-us.html'. Then when I changed its file extension to .php, it doesn't reflect on the server, it still looking for the 'contact-us.html' even though I already changed it so it always says 404 Not Found.

I tried restarting my XAMPP and repasting the folder but it still doesn't worked.

Comment: Can you add more info about how you are referencing this file? Because you only get 404 if the file is not on the server. So I will advise you to check the URL path. Eg 'contact-us.html' will not work for 'contact-us.php' also check your URL is your-domain/contact-us.php to get the file

Comment: Changing the filename won't change the links that point to it.

Comment: It can just be underlined what @Barmar said. *Check your links*. If changing the extension is the only thing you did, then this is the very first issue to address.